# Checking the control of an entity

Tags: java, performance

I have a method which checks if a control of an entity's attribute is 'multiControl' or not:

```
private boolean entityHasMultiControl(IEntityMetadata entityMetadata) {

    for(IAttributeMetadata attr : entityMetadata.getAttributes()){
        for(IControl control : attr.getAttributeType().getControls()){
            if(control.getIsMultiControl() == true)
                return true;
        }

    }
    return false;
}
```

Can this be simplified further in Java 8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that `entityMetadata.getAttributes()` and `attr.getAttributeType().getControls()` returns some kind of `Collection`, the answer is an absolute **YES**.

```
entityMetadata.getAttributes().stream()
    .flatMap(attr -> attr.getAttributeType().getControls().stream())
    .anyMatch(control -> control.getIsMultiControl());
```

Other notes:

- Comparing with `== true` is not necessary, that part could be removed entirely.
- Prefixing interfaces with `I` is not something commonly done in Java, it is not recommended in any naming conventions. It *is*, however, done in C#. C# is not Java.
- `getIsMultiControl` is a very weird name. Should preferably be named `isMultiControl`.

Comment: So this lambda expression would return false if none of attribute's control is multiControl?

Comment: @RanPaul Yes. Hence the `anyMatch` call (I just noticed I originally wrote `allMatch`, but it should be `anyMatch`). If anyone matches the lambda, it will return true. Otherwise, it will return false.